# Why is the strcmp function returning 1?

Tags: arrays, c, string, strcmp

The below code compares s[2] with the string "sw". Since I have assigned s[2] = "sw", shouldn't it return 1 when I use strcmp. But I am getting 0 as the value of i.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
  char s[2] = "sw";
  int i;
 
  i = strcmp(s, "sw");

  printf("%d",i);
}
```

Comment: Because `s` is of length `2` and is not `null`-terminated. Your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: To expand on the above comment: make it `s[3]` so there's space for the null terminator.

Comment: `char s[2] = "sw";` the array is to short, you forgot the trailing `'\0'`. It must be al least `char s[3]`

Comment: And `char s[] = "...";` will correctly allocate the 3 chars.

Answer (score 0):

C stringss require to be null character terminated. So the char array holding it has to have space for it.

```
int main () {
  char s[3] = "sw"; 
  int i;
 
  i = strcmp(s, "sw");

  printf("%d",i);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1Gs8WqG5h